# Ios core data not saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using core data and i have a problem. When i save the data and the app is still running i can see and get the data that was saved.

Once the application is close, all the fields deleted and just the object is saved. I can see that in the saveContext method. 
On first launch when the app is closing the saveContext method is activated. I can see that the managedObjectContext object is inserting new object.
The next times that the app is opening , the managedObjectContext is updating the object so i know it save the objects but when i try to retrive the object it can find .

here is how i insert objects:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    @try {
        UserData *userData  =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[UserTable tableName]                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        //Insert Values
        userData.facebookId=user.id;
        userData.name=user.name;
        userData.picoAccessToken=[PicoApiManager sharedInstance].accessToken;
        userData.picoExpire=[PicoApiManager sharedInstance].expires;
        userData.latitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:user.latitude];
        userData.longitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:user.longitude];
        userData.pushId=user.pushId;
        userData.isActive=[NSNumber numberWithBool:activeStatus];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
    }
```

or

```
  -(void)addPictures:(NSMutableArray *)Pictures;
 {
//Setting the isNew field to NO to all the pictures already in the db 
[self updateIsNewOfPicture];
for (Picture *picture in Pictures) {
//Checks if inserted picture is already inside the table

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    @try {
    PictureData *pictureData=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[PicturesTable     tableName]inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    //Insert Values
    pictureData.url=picture.source;
    pictureData.isNew=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    pictureData.isPick=[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    pictureData.timeTaken=picture.time_taken;
    pictureData.albumData=[self getActiveAlbum];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
    }
}
```

This is app delegate functions:

```
     - (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Pico-Db" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Pico.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

This is how i'm trying to get the data :

```
  AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //2
    // initializing NSFetchRequest
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //Setting Entity to be Queried
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[UserTable tableName] inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];


    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError* error;

    // Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
    NSArray *fetchedRecords = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedRecords.count >0) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `-[AppDelegate saveContext]` after inserting your data in order for CoreData to persist changes to disk. The `NSManagedObjectContext` will store changes in memory so while your application is still active, you will have access to the data. As soon as the app terminates, however, unless you call `-[AppDelegate saveContext]` those changes will not be persisted.

Try this in the first example:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate  = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

@try {
    UserData *userData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[UserTable tableName] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    //Insert Values
    userData.facebookId=user.id;
    userData.name=user.name;
    userData.picoAccessToken=[PicoApiManager sharedInstance].accessToken;
    userData.picoExpire=[PicoApiManager sharedInstance].expires;
    userData.latitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:user.latitude];
    userData.longitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:user.longitude];
    userData.pushId=user.pushId;
    userData.isActive=[NSNumber numberWithBool:activeStatus];

} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
}

// SAVE CONTEXT:
[appDelegate saveContext];
```

Try this in the second example:

```
for (Picture *picture in Pictures) {
    // Checks if inserted picture is already inside the table

    AppDelegate* appDelegate  = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    @try {
        PictureData *pictureData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[PicturesTable tableName]inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        //Insert Values
        pictureData.url=picture.source;
        pictureData.isNew=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        pictureData.isPick=[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        pictureData.timeTaken=picture.time_taken;
        pictureData.albumData=[self getActiveAlbum];

    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
    }
}

// SAVE CONTEXT:
[appDelegate saveContext];
```

To create a fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"YourEntityName"];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"attributeName" ascending:YES];
request.predicate       = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == %@", 13];

NSError *error   = nil; // 
NSArray *results = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (!results) {
    NSLog(@"Error performing fetch request: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

return ([results count] > 0); // There are more efficient ways of getting count from CoreData
```

Comment: Before the app terminate , in the applicationWillTerminate i'm calling the saveContext method. That currect? or i need every time i'm insertind data to call this function?

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is not guaranteed to be called. It should not be relied upon to save your `NSManagedObjectContext`. The context should be saved after inserting data, or at the next logical point in your application.

Comment: Hey, sorry but for some reason it's not helping.
The code that im using to get the information out it is ok?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Not sure why you need to go through the trouble of creating an `NSEntityDescription` when you can just pass in an entity name to the `NSFetchRequest` initializer.